# Flutter: Check contain number in list

Tags: flutter, list, dart

If have the following list of strings in my Flutter application.

```
numList = [for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) i.toString().padLeft(2, "0")];
```

It is a list from 00 to 99.

Now I would like to create two new lists out of it.

1. One that contains all strings containing a "0" (00,01,10,02,20...)
2. One that contains all strings starting with "1" (10,11,12,13...)

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  var numList = [for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
                  i.toString().padLeft(2, "0")];
  
  var numOfZeros=[];
  var numOfOnes=[];

// loop to check every element
for(int i=0;i<numList.length;i++){

// check if an element contains "0"

  if(numList[i].contains("0")){

    numOfZeros.add(numList[i]);
  }
  // check if an element contains "1" in its index
  if(numList[i][0].contains(RegExp("1"))){
    numOfOnes.add(numList[i]);

  }
}



print(numOfOnes);
//print(numList[91][1]);
//print(numOfZeros);
//   print("$numList");
//   print(numZero);
//   print(numList[10]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
List<string> containingZero = []
List<string> startingWithOne = []
for (var numberString in numList) {
    if (numberString[0] == "1") {
        startingWithOne.append(numberString)
    }
    if (numberString.contains("0")) {
        containingZero(numberString)
    }
}
```

First, you iterate over all strings in the list. And within that iteration, you can check the individual characters with methods such as `contains()` and access individual letters just like in any list